# zabbix monitor JMX C3P0 tokenid

Tags: jmx, c3p0, zabbix

the key is:

```
jmx["com.mchange.v2.c3p0:identityToken=2yaf3o9m1taosztt7mari|2294069,name=2yaf3o9m1taosztt7mari|2294069,type=PooledDataSource",maxPoolSize]
```

but the identityToken changed when restart the tomcat.
is there a macro to define it,adapt when changed?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5vg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure c3p0's JMX key to be something that will not change.

Please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management

The simple story is:

1. Be sure to set the c3p0 configuration property `dataSourceName`, which will become the value of a name attribute in the JMX key;
2. Set (in a `c3p0.properties` file or as a system property or in typesafe-config file) `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true`

If you are using a `c3p0.properties file`, it'd be something like

```
c3p0.dataSourceName=myPooledDataSource
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true
```